# $(document).height() no workey

Tags: jquery, dom

Why are the 3rd and 4th inputs not being populated?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
label {
    display:block;
}
</style>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <label for="WindowHeight">Window Height:</label>
    <input name="WindowHeight">
    <label for="WindowWidth">Window Width:</label>
    <input name="WindowWidth">
    <label for="DocumentHeight">Document Height:</label>
    <input name="DocumentHeight">
    <label for="DocumentWidth">Document Width:</label>
    <input name="DocumentWidth">
</form>
<script>
function Populate() {
    $('input[name=WindowHeight]').val($(window).height());
    $('input[name=WindowWidth]').val($(window).width());
    $('input[name=DocumentHeight').val($(document).height());
    $('input[name=DocumentWidth').val($(document).width());
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    Populate();
});
Populate();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing two `]`s:

```
function Populate() {
    $('input[name=WindowHeight]').val($(window).height());
    $('input[name=WindowWidth]').val($(window).width());
    $('input[name=DocumentHeight]').val($(document).height());
    //                        --^
    $('input[name=DocumentWidth]').val($(document).width());
    //                       --^
}
```

Comment: @AIR how long were you staring at that one?  :)

Comment: Just say it Michael, they're "brackets"

Answer (score 3):

You are missing closing brackets here:

```
$('input[name=DocumentHeight').val($(document).height());
$('input[name=DocumentWidth').val($(document).width());
```